# Converting NETCDF Data to Tidy DataFrame in R

Tags: r

I am trying to get average Surface Sea Temperatures at each coordinate for the year 2021. I downloaded 2021 Daily Means for SST from NOAA. It is stored in a netcdf file but I am having trouble converting it into data frame.

I've gotten to the code below where I have an array but am unable to figure out where to proceed from here.

Id like it to have columns :
latitude ---- longitude ---- Surface Seat Temperature ---- Date

https://downloads.psl.noaa.gov/Datasets/noaa.oisst.v2.highres/sst.day.mean.2021.v2.nc

Here is the link to the data.

```
library(ncdf4)



ncpath <- "/Users/Downloads/"
ncname <- "sst.day.mean.2021.v2"  
ncfname <- paste(ncpath, ncname, ".nc", sep="")
dname <- "sst"  


ncin <- nc_open(ncfname)
print(ncin)


lon <- ncvar_get(ncin,"lon")
nlon <- dim(lon)
head(lon)

lat <- ncvar_get(ncin,"lat")
nlat <- dim(lat)
head(lat)

time <- ncvar_get(ncin,"time")
time
tunits <- ncatt_get(ncin,"time","units")
tunits
nt <- dim(time)
nt

sstunits <- ncatt_get(ncin,"sst","units")
sstunits

sst_array <- ncvar_get(ncin,dname)
dlname <- ncatt_get(ncin,dname,"long_name")
dunits <- ncatt_get(ncin,dname,"units")
missing_value <- ncatt_get(ncin,dname,"missing_value")
dim(sst_array)


title <- ncatt_get(ncin,0,"title")
institution <- ncatt_get(ncin,0,"institution")
datasource <- ncatt_get(ncin,0,"source")
references <- ncatt_get(ncin,0,"References")
dataset_title <- ncatt_get(ncin,0,"dataset_title")
version <- ncatt_get(ncin,0,"version")
```

Comment: Look into the tidync package which is designed with this kind of thing on mind

Answer (score 0):

I hate working with netcdf files and find them much easier to manage in rasters. So, I usually switch files to raster using `brick()`. Depending on the layers in your data (climate models, time, other variables, etc.) , it can be really as simple as that one function. If you have more layers, you have to add in a few extra arguments.

For example - putting it in a raster brick will likely put it in one layer per time period (not knowing the exact setup of your data), so if your data is daily then it will have one layer per day, then you can turn into a dataframe from there for each day's average value or something similar to add the extra step of processing you'll need to get things into a data-frame-able format. Otherwise, it's a bit harder to get netcdf data straight into a dataframe because there are several dimensions and variables that don't fit neatly into one table.